# Proper pull to refresh

Tags: ios, pull-to-refresh

Is there any working pull to refresh lib?

PullToRefresh-master not works

SVPullToRefresh-master have errors

ODRefreshControl-master - not like I want

Comment: show us your code so we can help

Answer (score 2):

There are many Libraries available, but I recommend you to use [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html).
 Apple has introduced UIRefreshControl in iOS6. You can integrate it in your UITableViewController using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    // Configure Refresh Control
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Configure View Controller
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
}
```

the refresh: method will trigger the update and you can stop it in your API callback using:

```
 [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
```

Comment: Check this link too http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/iOS-6-Pull-to-Refresh-(UIRefreshControl).aspx